# How to write LaTeX style math in notebook (as text)

Tags: front-end, notebooks, formatting, latex

If I have a notebook and I am just typing out ideas, I would like to be able to write math just as TeX style formatting for display and not as input to Mathematica.

I have found that I can use CTRL-4 to enter TeX style input, but the problem is that I cannot enter multiline equations or aligned environments like below...

```
\begin{aligned}
f(x) &= \int_0^1 x^2 dx \\
&= \frac{(1)^3}{3} - \frac{(0)^3}{3} \\
\end{aligned}
```

Is it possible to enter math like this for display in Mathematica?

Comment: `align` is a math environment. So you should not be using "$$" at all around it. Then it works. But the generated cell is not sized well and the math is hard to read. There might be a way around this issue of cell size. I do not know now.  This TeX input is new and still has bugs in it.

Comment: @Nasser, I originally tried to write math on this website with $$, that is a typo and not what I was trying to write in Mathematica. I cannot even get the align environment to work in Mathematica. Is there a way to makr CTRL-4 do a multiline input?

Comment: Do others agree it's a bug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

align is a math environment. So you should not be using "$$" at all around it. Then it works. But the generated cell is not sized well and the math is hard to read.

From [help](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/menuitem/InlineTeXInput.html)  on Insert ▶ Inline TeX Input it says

> inline math–mode

Which for me means it will not work with align as this is not inline math.

[image]

Also do not add `\\` at the end of the last line in `align`. This will result in uneeded extra space at the end which does not look good.

As a work around, and since this is just for display, why not use [MaTeX](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/MaTeXInstall/)?

```
MaTeX["
\\begin{aligned}
f(x) &= \\int_0^1 x^2 dx \\\\
&= \\frac{(1)^3}{3} - \\frac{(0)^3}{3}
\\end{aligned}
", Magnification -> 2]
```

Which gives

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: How do I get MaTeX to work? It doesn't seem to be a function on my plain Mathematica install

Comment: @Joff  Oh, Matex is an extra package that you need to install.  see [MateX](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/MaTeXInstall/)  Added link in the answer also.

Answer (score 5):

***Caveat:** While playing with this trying to get an exact replica of TeX, I occasionally crashed the front end. (Ouch.) Probably because I made a typo in editing the cell expression. I think the code below is safe, but I felt I should warn people.  I can't prove that I'm right. It's mainly to demonstrate how the bug could be fixed.*

It seems to be a bug, which should be reported to WRI.  There's a missing `BoxData` and possibly a missing `FormBox`. (The resulting boxes are more elaborate than needed, but the elaboration might be the result of a straightforward programming approach -- that is, each item in the alignment grid gets its own `Cell[]`.)  Anyway, the following hack of internals fixes aligned equations with the setting of `$fixEquationAlignment` below, and it may break other alignments (slightly). One might be able to figure out a setting for `$fixEquationAlignment` in other cases, but if you mix alignments in one TeX cell, then probably you have to go in and edit the cell expression directly.

```
(* How to unset the damage done below *)
System`Convert`TeXImportDump`TeXImport[args__] /; ! 
   TrueQ[$pleaseFixAlignment] =.

(*this fixes aligned equations*)
$fixEquationAlignment = {"Columns" -> {Right, {Left}},
 "Rows" -> {{Baseline}}};
DownValues[System`Convert`TeXImportDump`TeXImport] = 
  Join[{HoldPattern[
      System`Convert`TeXImportDump`TeXImport[args__] /; ! 
        TrueQ[$pleaseFixAlignment]] :> 
     Block[{$pleaseFixAlignment = True}, 
      System`Convert`TeXImportDump`TeXImport[args] /.
        Cell[RowBox[data__], rest___] :> 
         Cell[BoxData@FormBox[RowBox[data], TraditionalForm], rest] /.
       g_GridBox :> 
        Append[g, GridBoxAlignment -> $fixEquationAlignment]]}, 
   DownValues[System`Convert`TeXImportDump`TeXImport]];
```

[image]

Note that it does not really do TeX: Mathematica translates TeX into its own boxes.  It does a pretty good job, but there are differences.

---

*Update: Version 2*

This produces both a simpler box structure and better spacing for equations:

```
(*How to unset the damage done below*)
System`Convert`TeXImportDump`TeXImport[args__] /; !TrueQ[$pleaseFixAlignment] =.

(*this fixes aligned equations*)
$fixEquationAlignment = {"Columns" -> {Right, {Left}}, "Rows" -> {{Baseline}}};
DownValues[System`Convert`TeXImportDump`TeXImport] = 
  Join[{HoldPattern[
      System`Convert`TeXImportDump`TeXImport[args__] /; ! 
        TrueQ[$pleaseFixAlignment]] :> 
     Block[{$pleaseFixAlignment = True}, 
      System`Convert`TeXImportDump`TeXImport[args] /.
        Cell[TextData[{" ", Cell[b_, ___], ___}], ___] :> b /.
       g_GridBox :> 
        Join[g, 
         GridBox[GridBoxAlignment -> $fixEquationAlignment, 
          GridBoxSpacings -> {"Columns" -> {Offset[
               0.27999999999999997`], {Offset[0.]}, 
              Offset[0.27999999999999997`]}, 
            "Rows" -> {Offset[0.2], {Offset[0.4]}, Offset[0.2]}}]]]}, 
   DownValues[System`Convert`TeXImportDump`TeXImport]];
```

[image]

Or one can postprocess a cell by executing this below the cell with TeX (uses `$fixEquationAlignment`):

```
NotebookWrite[
 PreviousCell[],
 NotebookRead@PreviousCell[] /.
   Cell[TextData[{" ", Cell[b_, ___], ___}], ___] :> b /.
  g_GridBox :> 
   Join[g, 
    GridBox[GridBoxAlignment -> $fixEquationAlignment, 
     GridBoxSpacings -> {"Columns" -> {Offset[
          0.27999999999999997`], {Offset[0.]}, 
         Offset[0.27999999999999997`]}, 
       "Rows" -> {Offset[0.2], {Offset[0.4]}, Offset[0.2]}}]]
 ]
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a hack to get control-4 to use `MaTeX` (see http://szhorvat.net/pelican/latex-typesetting-in-mathematica.html and [`MaTeXInstall[]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/MaTeXInstall/)) to format TeX in inline cells:

```
(* How to unset the damage done below *)
InputAssistant`TeXStringToBoxes // Unprotect;
InputAssistant`TeXStringToBoxes[s_String] /; TrueQ@$useMaTeXQ =.;
InputAssistant`TeXStringToBoxes // Protect;

(* use MaTeX to format inline TeX *)
Needs@"MaTeX`";
$useMaTeXMag = 1;
$useMaTeXBaselineShift = 0;
InputAssistant`TeXStringToBoxes // Unprotect;
InputAssistant`TeXStringToBoxes[s_String] /; TrueQ@$useMaTeXQ :=
  AdjustmentBox[
   ToBoxes@MaTeX[s, Magnification -> $useMaTeXMag],
   BoxBaselineShift -> $useMaTeXBaselineShift];
InputAssistant`TeXStringToBoxes // Protect;

$useMaTeXQ = True;
```

[image]

The parameters are included because first trial was `x^2`, and the result did not align well with text in a Text cell.  So I made some adjustments:

```
$useMaTeXMag = 1.44; (* x^2 and x have the ~same size in a Text cell *)
$useMaTeXBaselineShift = -0.12;  (* aligns x^2 with x in a Text cell *)
```

[image]

You may wish to test some parameters and the `MaTeX` options such as `ContentPadding` before fixing a style for a document.  There's no way to encode Mathematica parameter assignments in the inline-TeX input mechanism that I've discovered.  Of course, it might make the most sense to encode the magnification in TeX itself. This could be done with the option `"Preamble"` and a `$useMaTeXPreamble` variable, so that you wouldn't have to type it in every instance of TeX input.

I wonder if the Inline TeX Input assistant can be cloned, to create an independent Inline MaTeX assistant or to call any other external service and insert boxes in a cell. (Obviously, one cannot have control-4 do more than one thing, but one could use a palette.) The `` InputAssistant` ``  context seems to deal only with TeX, but the name suggests the functionality could be expanded.

*Update: Newlines*

You can't type a newline (return) directly, since it cause the FE to call the display function (TeX/MaTeX). You can type `\[NewLine]`, the character code `\.0a`, or type out the TeX, copy it and paste it in.  I pasted the OP's TeX code and didn't think of trying to type it until @ChrisK commented.

Comment: Wow!  How do you enter multiple lines as in your first example?  When I hit ctrl-4, then `\begin {aligned}`, the first return key sends it to evaluate, resulting in `$Failed`.

Comment: @ChrisK I pasted the OP's input. I didn't realized entering it would be a problem. :) However, you can type `\[NewLine]` and it works. -- Just had a thought and [thought] it worked too: Shift-return enters a newline. NOPE. Shift-return enters `\[LineSeparator]` and fails. Have to enter `\[NewLine]` I guess.

Comment: This probably isn't the place to ask, but is there some way to just get a LaTeX cell, hit shift-return, and it gets typeset?  Something like and `ExternalLanguage` cell.

Comment: @ChrisK Something like this?: `CellPrint[TextCell["edit me", "Text", Evaluatable -> True, CellEvaluationFunction -> (NotebookWrite[EvaluationCell[], Cell[BoxData[MakeBoxes[#, StandardForm] &@MaTeX[#]], "Output"]] &)]]`. The Cell options could be set in stylesheet. The style of the output need not be `"Output"`. For text, you might want an inline cell: `CellPrint[TextCell["edit me", "Text", Evaluatable -> True, CellEvaluationFunction -> (NotebookWrite[EvaluationCell[], Cell[TextData[Cell[BoxData[MakeBoxes[#, StandardForm] &@MaTeX[#]], "InlineFormula"]], "Text"]] &)]]`

Comment: That's pretty good, but not quite what I had in mind.  I'll ask a proper question some time when the need becomes pressing.  thanks!

Comment: @ChrisK Okay. `TemplateBox[]` seems like it might handle it if set up right. That's how inline TeX is done. It's sufficiently complicated that I don't have time to investigate right now. It may have the same problem with entering newlines, though.

Comment: Yeah don't worry about it, more of an idle thought at this point.

Answer (score 2):

Inline $\TeX$ Input works well:

[image]

I don't know if $\LaTeX$ environments can be used for multiline equations in a Notebook, but a somewhat improvised solution is to use spaces in $\LaTeX$ math mode.

Comment: I would hardly call that working well. It requires manually spacing all of the elements to get them aligned

Comment: That's why I mentioned that it's kind of improvised. MaTeX is a better solution because you can even load packages with the preamble option.