How can I format an array using TeX array environment within a text cell?
I'm currently experiencing a really frustrating problem while using the typesetting functionalities of Mathematica. I've been writing large blocks of text explaining much of the code that follows the text, and many times I have utilized writing this directly in a Text Cell, which I open/start using Alt+7 on Windows. When I want to write an equation in the text cell I use Ctrl+4 and it allows me to write using some basic TeX typesetting. When I need equations to mimic LaTeX display-math mode, I go to Palettes > Writing Assistant > Math Cells > Marker Aligned Math, then within that cell, I'll then use Ctrl+4 to invoke another TeX interpreter. The problem I've run into though is the TeX interpreter can't properly handle array environments. For example, if I write the following within the TeX interpreter created by Ctrl+4,
\begin{array}{cc} f_{+}(x) & \text{for } x>0\\ f_{-}(x) & \text{for } x\leq0 \end{array}

I get this as its result:

Which quite clearly does not look write at all. I believe this is likely because the mode that is invoked using Ctrl+4 is inline math and that likely is not meant to render arrays properly, but I could be wrong with that conjecture. The things I've tried to directly prevent this strange formating are:

Use ~ instead of whitespaces between each character in the environment, i.e f_{+}~(~x~)&\text{for}~x~>~0: Didn't Do Anything
Enclose the entire expressions of each cell of the array within curly brackets, i.e. {f_{+}(x)} & {\text{for } x>0} Didn't Do Anything
Give each symbol there own cell, i.e. f_{+}&(&x&)&\text{for}&x&>&0 (I did change the number of c's as the passed option to the array enviornment): Kind of worked but symbols were too spaced out and I got a "Why the Beep?" error which read:


There was a syntax error on line 3 of an internally generated string.
The error was: Cell[BoxData[ FormBox[

If I then tried to click on the rendered TeX it crashed Mathematica, so I'm not to keen on following that forward with as a potential solution
These are all the routes forward I've tried. I know there is likely a solution using MaTeX and something with the PrintCell[] command, which if is unsolvable otherwise I'd certainly go with. However, I'd really like to maintain the kind of "flow" I have by writing things directly in a Text Cell and calling a TeX interpreter using Ctrl+4. Additionally, I am aware that I could use Mathematica's pre-set typesets for arrays by going to Palettes > Writing Assistant > Typesetting where there are preset arrays to choose from, but the resulting equations have a different font/look to them than what I get when I write using TeX. I understand this is a classic "beggars can't be choosers" kind of scenario, but having to change the way I format my TeX/equations in a part of my document midly triggers my hyperfixation. If anyone has any ideas on how to fix this, I would greatly appreciate some insight.

Mathematica has a perfectly good way to enter matrices using keyboard shortcuts. I suggest you learn to use it. It will be much faster than fussing with LaTeX, and it will save you a lot of pain.

Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! Which version of Mathematica are you using? In version 14.1, I don't see any troubles. I've used CTRL+4 to insert your $\TeX$.

@Domen It says 14.0. I can try updating to 14.1 and see if the issue still persists

Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/263698/1871

I upgraded to 14.1 and indeed the issue is entirely gone. I suppose this just would have been considered a bug in 14.0?

Not sure if it's a bug fix or enhancement. (The limitation/bug is there from the beginning. )

For the sake of completeness and for those who may be experiencing the same issue and who are not able to upgrade to 14.1, where this is not being exhibited, here is a workaround. For each cell of the array, put what information you have inside \text{$...$}. For whatever reason, this prevents the rendering from pushing all the symbols vertically like in the picture. So, instead of
\begin{array}{cc} f_{+}(x) & \text{for } x>0\\ f_{-}(x) & \text{for } x\leq0 \end{array}

You would write
\begin{array}{ccc} \text{$f_{+}(x)$} & \text{for} & \text{$x>0$}\\ \text{$f_{-}(x)$} & \text{for} & \text{$x\leq0$} \end{array}

